# Retrofit: How to get the size of Request and Response?

Tags: logging, retrofit

I am developing an android app and using retrofit to send requests and get responses. Like this:

```
public interface Service {
    @POST("/GetInfo")
    InfoResponse getInfo(@Body InfoRequest request);
}
```

I want to know how much data it will be used when doing these requests.

I find if I set the LogLevel for retrofit, it could print out the size in log.

For request:

> ```
> ---> HTTP POST http://....
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Content-Length: 516
> ---> END HTTP (522-byte body)
> ```

For response:

> ```
> <--- HTTP 200  http://....
> :HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
> Content-Type: application/json 
> <--- END HTTP (420394-byte body)
> ```

This 522-byte and 420394-byte information what I want. Is there any way to get it directly without getting the log and parsing it?

If I have to use this log in order to calculate the size, any good way to get the size from log and then show on android?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrofit 2 - Is it possible to get the size of a JSON that I'm sending and receiving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629502/retrofit-2-is-it-possible-to-get-the-size-of-a-json-that-im-sending-and-recei)

Answer (score 1):

You can add network intecepter in you retrofit builder and check size using
`responseBody.source().apply{request(Long.MAX_VALUE)}.buffer.size` for response 
and `request.body.contentLength()` for request